# What are the basic requirements for Android device driver development?

Tags: android

I'm totally new to both android and Linux. I've to write a driver for Android phone to read all the messages.

Questions:

1. What OS, should I select?
2. If Linux; then with which flavor and version should I go?
3. From where should I begin my Android device driver learning to accomplish my task?
4. Do I need to install any SDK on my windows system to develop Android device driver or simply I should prepare linux system for Android work?

Kindly guide me with better beginning points

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that might help you

http://mobilesystemsengineering.appspot.com/staticdocs/AdvancedMobileSystemsEngineering/lecturenotes/Chapter4.pdf